# Jetpack compose text alignment not updating in emulator or real android device

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

A very basic code it is:

Just a simple hello world with some styling and text aligned to center.
The text is aligned to center in preview but not in emulator or real android device.

Here's the complete code:

```
package com.example.jetpackcomposetutorial

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.jetpackcomposetutorial.ui.theme.JetpackComposeTutorialTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SayHello()
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun SayHello(name:String = "World"){
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name",
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
        color = Color.Red,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 30.sp
    )
}
```

1. [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxfgo.png)
2. [Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAeT.png)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem in the `Preview` because it's not supposed to be shown in the middle because you didn't specify any **container** for the text or a size.

to be clear you saying `TextAlign.Center` does not mean text will be centred in the screen instead it means the text will be centred in the width giving to the `Text`.

a simple fix like this should work:

```
@Composable
fun SayHello(name:String = "World"){
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name",
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
        color = Color.Red,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        //add this
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

because we added `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` now this means the text will take max width, now `TextAlign.Center` will take action because it has a bunch of space available so it will put any text giving to it the middle.